# how to take screenshot for a captcha and put it in the JFrame

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm developing my first java software as project, using what I learned from the college.
I'm trying to transform this website that students using it to get results to a software.

Sorry, the website is in french language, use google to translate the page.

url: https://www2.inscription.tn/ORegMx/servlet/AuthentificationEtud?ident=cin

The website have a captcha that the user need to see it to write it.
The link need to be loaded one time so the captcha didn't change. So I'm thinking about taking a screenshot of the captcha of the opening link and put the image in the `JFrame`.

Please check the design before the code

[image]

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.navigate().to("https://www4.inscription.tn/ORegMx/servlet/AuthentificationEtud?ident=cin");              


WebElement c = driver.findElement(By.name("cin"));
WebElement d = driver.findElement(By.id("dn"));
WebElement cap = driver.findElement(By.id("cincap"));

String cin = CIN.getText();
String date = daten.getText();
String capp = code.getText();

// fill the fields
c.sendKeys(cin);
d.sendKeys(date);
cap.sendKeys(capp);

// Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
cap.submit();
```

Can I get screenshot without firefox or google chrome? Use only HtmlUnitDriver?
Please someone tell me what to do and after taking the screenshot of the captcha( captcha element by alt capito) how can I put it in the `JFrame`?

I'm using windowbuilder pro in eclipse.